# Convert large byteArray to wordArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, encryption, type-conversion, cryptojs

I need to convert a large array (Uint8Array(224337596)) inside my code. Apparently the size is to big and makes the browser crash.

Is there any workaround to maybe to this in chunks?

```
var encrypted = convertUint8ArrayToWordArray(mergedArray)

function convertUint8ArrayToWordArray(u8Array) {
    var words = [], i = 0, len = u8Array.length;

    while (i < len) {
        words.push(
            (u8Array[i++] << 24) |
            (u8Array[i++] << 16) |
            (u8Array[i++] << 8)  |
            (u8Array[i++])
        );
    }

    return {
        sigBytes: words.length * 4,
        words: words
    };
}
```

Comment: I couldn't make my browser crash with it, is it taking too long or the result array is too big?

Comment: Looking at your recent questions, including the bountied one, all relating to processing a large amount of data on the client, I wonder if there's a bigger architectural question to be asked, including what's the data for, and whether you control the server, and what are the clients' and client permissions, and so on.  Knowing only what I can piece together from recent questions, I think the answer will tilt toward moving more processing to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser window freezes, than you can process the array asynchronously in batches. I've put the example into snippet

```js
function pause() {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0))
}

async function convertUint8ArrayToWordArray(u8Array) {
    var words = [], i = 0, len = u8Array.length;

    while (i < len) {
        words.push(
            (u8Array[i++] << 24) |
            (u8Array[i++] << 16) |
            (u8Array[i++] << 8)  |
            (u8Array[i++])
        );
      if (i % 100000 == 0) {
        await pause();
      }
    }

    return {
        sigBytes: words.length * 4,
        words: words
    };
}

const bigArray = new Uint8Array(224337596);
for (let idx = 0; idx < bigArray.length; ++idx) {
  bigArray[idx] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}


convertUint8ArrayToWordArray(bigArray).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.words[0])
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but does not solve the problem. Browser now crashes after a while. i guess when the Promises stack up.